# set the border opacity using jquery or javascript in the case of color value in hexadecimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I get border-width,border-color dynamically.

I have to set the opacity for the border.but the border-color value is in the hexadecimal format.

```
var borderCSS = { border: borderWidth + "px solid "+borderColor};
```

**output is:**

```
 border:10px solid #cccccc;
```

I don't know how to set the border opacity in this case using `jquery` 
or `javascript.`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this case, you have to convert your Hex color to RGB. I just converted Hex to RGB and then used your code to produce the color property:

```
var borderColor ="#cccccc";
borderWidth=3;
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}
R = hexToRgb(borderColor).r;
G = hexToRgb(borderColor).g;
B = hexToRgb(borderColor).b;
var borderCSS = "border: "+borderWidth+"px solid rgba("+R+", "+G+", "+B+", "+.5+")";
```

.5 is opacity value

Comment: is there an inbuilt function called `hexToR();` ?

Comment: I tested the code and it worked perfectly. borderCSS is a string variable and all you need to do is to set borderCSS to your DIV's style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

use css() method for setting the border opacity.
try using following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var borderWidth='10';
    var borderColor='#CCCCCC';
    var borderCSS=borderWidth+'px solid '+borderColor;
    $('h1').css('border',borderCSS);
});
```

or else refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmk66yrw/1/)